# Select Record with blank field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access database with several headers

for this question lets just say i have header1, header2 and header3

what i want to do is get the last item with a blank field for header3 since both header1 and header2 already have data in them.

what i have for now:

```
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
 Dim sqlstr As String
 Dim header1, header2, header3 as field

 Set db = CurrentDb()
 Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("TblToMonitor")

 sqlstr = "Select * from [Mytable] Where [header3] IS NULL OR len(Nz([header3])) =0;"

 docmd.runsql(sqlstr)

 with rst
      .edit
      .fields("header3") = "Done"
      .update
 end with
```

when i run the code, it selects the first row then updates the header3 field with done but does not move to the next next record.

any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In order to update all rows you need to enclose the update part in a loop :

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim header1, header2, header3 as field

Set db = CurrentDb()    

sqlstr = "Select * from [Mytable] Where [header3] IS NULL OR len(Nz([header3])) =0;"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sqlstr) 
with rst
    While not .EOF
        .edit
        .fields("header3") = "Done"
        .update
        .MoveNext
    Wend
end with
```